# Trying to compile SDL1.2.14 but make fails

Tags: software-installation, sdl

```
~/SDL-1.2.14/ $ make
/bin/bash config.status Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
Warning, configure.in is out of date
#(cd . && sh autogen.sh && sh configure)
/bin/bash build-scripts/mkinstalldirs build
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL.c  -o build/SDL.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL.c -o build/SDL.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_error.c  -o build/SDL_error.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_error.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_error.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_error.c -o build/SDL_error.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_fatal.c  -o build/SDL_fatal.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_fatal.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_fatal.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/SDL_fatal.c -o build/SDL_fatal.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audio.c  -o build/SDL_audio.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audio.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_audio.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audio.c -o build/SDL_audio.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiocvt.c  -o build/SDL_audiocvt.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiocvt.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_audiocvt.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiocvt.c -o build/SDL_audiocvt.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiodev.c  -o build/SDL_audiodev.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiodev.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_audiodev.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_audiodev.c -o build/SDL_audiodev.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer.c  -o build/SDL_mixer.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_mixer.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer.c -o build/SDL_mixer.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX.c  -o build/SDL_mixer_MMX.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_mixer_MMX.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX.c -o build/SDL_mixer_MMX.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.c  -o build/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.c -o build/SDL_mixer_MMX_VC.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_m68k.c  -o build/SDL_mixer_m68k.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_m68k.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_mixer_m68k.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_mixer_m68k.c -o build/SDL_mixer_m68k.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_wave.c  -o build/SDL_wave.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_wave.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_wave.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/audio/SDL_wave.c -o build/SDL_wave.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cdrom/SDL_cdrom.c  -o build/SDL_cdrom.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cdrom/SDL_cdrom.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_cdrom.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cdrom/SDL_cdrom.c -o build/SDL_cdrom.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cpuinfo/SDL_cpuinfo.c  -o build/SDL_cpuinfo.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cpuinfo/SDL_cpuinfo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_cpuinfo.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/cpuinfo/SDL_cpuinfo.c -o build/SDL_cpuinfo.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/events/SDL_active.c  -o build/SDL_active.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/events/SDL_active.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_active.o
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/events/SDL_active.c -o build/SDL_active.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden    -D_REENTRANT    -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/events/SDL_events.c  -o build/SDL_events.lo
libtool: compile:  clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DHAVE_LINUX_VERSION_H -c ./src/events/SDL_events.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_events.o
./src/events/SDL_events.c:90:43: error: unused parameter 'unused' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
static int SDLCALL SDL_GobbleEvents(void *unused)
                                          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/SDL_events.lo] Error 1
```

I'm new to Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Why are you trying to build SDL from source anyway?

Comment: 14.04.5 LTS. And I am trying it  because I searched how  to install SDL  and I followed the instructions. If there is a another way please let me know. Thanks

Comment: In Ubuntu, you should always try to install packages from the repository if possible. What is your end goal? Why do you need SDL? The answer to that question will determine whether you need just the runtime package or the development package.

Comment: I need SDL because I need to install libgraph library for graphics.

Comment: How did you obtain and configure the source of SDL-1.2.14? If you are following instructions, please add a link to them

Comment: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/01/how-to-install-sdl-12-simple.html?m=1